# A Query in the Query Store shows high Logical Reads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-store

When I look at the Query Store reports for **Top Resource Consuming Queries**,
there is one query that skews the report so much that I can barely see the next query because this one is so high.

Highest one:
Total logical reads: 12956022792
execution count:     2458
plan count:          6

The next highest one:
Total logical reads: 76670280
execution count:     106
plan count:          1

What are some recommendations for improving this query?

Here is the plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1AlsOMn-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Remove the `OPTION(FORCE ORDER)`. This greatly limits the optimizer's freedom to find a good plan.
- Modify the Index Seek indexes to include the columns referenced in the following Key Lookup operators (Output List **and** Predicate)
- Capture actual (post-execution) plans for representative executions.
- Consider adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` if different executions require different plan shapes to run well, or `OPTIMIZE FOR` hints for the main cases.

If nothing else, attempt to capture a post-execution plan for a problematic case, as the basis for your tuning efforts.